# How do I change the source of an iframe from a PHP if statement using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, iframe

Based on the result of a PHP if statement, I want to change the source attribute of an iframe.

I have the following:

```
<?PHP
     if {...}
     else {
          echo "<script>";
          echo "document.getElementById('video-embed').setAttribute('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ');";
          echo "</script>";
     }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
     <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <iframe id="video-embed" src="...some other youtube video"></iframe>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

I know that executing valid JavaScript from the if statement is at least feasible, as I've succesfully tested JS alerts. Everything I've seen online has seemed to indicate that the syntax in question for the line "document.getElem..." is valid. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: PHP is executed on the server, well before any JS code runs, so adding JS code to the page through PHP is a little redundant. Just set the iframe src directly in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the Javascript before the HTML that creates the element that it's trying to modify, so `getElementById()` isn't finding the element. Move the PHP code that adds the JS to the end of the HTML, so that the ID will be found. Or put the Javascript in the window's `load` handler.

```
<?PHP
     if {...}
     else {
          echo "<script>";
          echo "window.addEventListener('load', function() {";
          echo "document.getElementById('video-embed').setAttribute('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ');";
          echo "});";
          echo "</script>";
     }
?>
```

Comment: this solved my problem. I was missing the "window.addEventListener..." line